# Find missing date in List<DateTime> and insert that date on the right index

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, for-loop, foreach

Say I have a List with the following dates.

```
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
dateList.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 01));
dateList.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 02));
dateList.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 03));
dateList.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 04));
dateList.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 06));
dateList.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 08));
```

How can I iterate through the dateList, find the DateTimes missing (2002-01-05 and 2002-01-07), then create those DateTimes and add them to the dateList on the correct index?

Comment: An option would be to generate a new list with the dates missing. Is that an option?

Comment: Is there any point in avoiding SortedList?

Comment: I was able to extract the missing dates, but wasnt sure of how to insert them into the dateList, on the correct index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following approach that determines the min- and max-dates and the TimeSpan difference and then generates the list:

```
DateTime min = dateList.Min();
DateTime max = dateList.Max();
TimeSpan diff = max - min;
dateList = Enumerable.Range(0, diff.Days + 1).Select(d => min.AddDays(d)).ToList();
```

You need to use `diff.Days + 1` to include the end-date.

If you can't use LINQ for whatever reason you could use a for-loop and `List.Insert`, but you have to use `List.Sort` beforehand if you aren't sure whether the list is sorted or not:

```
dateList.Sort();
if (dateList.Count > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dateList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        DateTime currrent = dateList[i].Date;
        DateTime next = dateList[i + 1].Date;
        DateTime expected = currrent.AddDays(1);
        if (next != expected)
        {
            dateList.Insert(++i, expected);
        }
    }
}
```

You see how much more readable the LINQ version is.

Comment: @bensij: edited my answer to provide a non-LINQ approach to show how grey the world would be without LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to loop and find missing dates, and add it into a new list. At the end, join the two list and reorder by date. Not the best performance, but the simple to understand/maintain.

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
dates.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 01));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 02));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 03));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 04));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 06));
dates.Add(new DateTime(2002, 01, 08));

// algo works only if dates are in order
dates = dates.OrderBy(date => date).ToList();

var missingDates = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < dates.Count; i++)
{
    var diff = (dates[i + 1] - dates[i]).TotalDays;
    for(int iToComplete = 1; iToComplete < diff; iToComplete++)
    {
        missingDates.Add(dates[i].AddDays(iToComplete));
    }
}
dates.AddRange(missingDates);
dates = dates.OrderBy(date => date).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice to see different ways of solving it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just generate list of all dates when you have start and end date. And then use `Except` to find dates missing in original list:

```
var startDate = dateList.Min();
var endDate = dateList.Max();

var allDates = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days)
                         .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i));

var missingDates = allDates.Except(dateList);
```

Missing dates:

> 1/5/2002
>   1/7/2002